# Mysql: Not more than 10 but at least 3 results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table showing distances between cities like:

```
CREATE TABLE `distances` (
`city1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`city2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`distance` double(12,4) DEFAULT NULL);
```

What I need is a query which shows all cities which are at not more than 20 km distance to a given city (with lets say key "1"). And I want a maximum of 10 cities, so this seems easy so far:

```
SELECT city2, distance FROM distances WHERE
city1='1'
AND distance <= 20
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

But: I want to have at least 3 cities displayed which means if there is only 1 city within 20 km radius, I need to add 2 cities with more then 20 km distance to the given city (best ordered by distance ASC as well), like:

```
Result:
city key 7: 18 km
city key 24: 22 km
city key 4: 23 km
```

How can I add this to my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it all in only one query, you should be able to do as follows. The idea is that you ONLY list more than 3 answers IF the answers after the third position are within the 20 mile/km bounds.

```
SET @index=0;
SELECT @index:=@index+1 AS `index`
     , t.city2
     , t.distance
FROM (SELECT * from distances ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10) t
WHERE t.city1='1'
  AND (t.distance <= 20 OR @index <= 3)
```

*Edit :* thanks to notulysses for improvements to performance and style. Thanks to Gordon for actually catching that it didn't work ;)

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b346/10) (there is a syntax improvement, as you can't refer to column aliases in the `WHERE`clause).

Comment: I peeked but didn't notice a syntax improvement; what was it?

Comment: escaping the reserved word `index` and referring to a local variable instead of column alias.

Comment: adopted those, with attribution. Thanks.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that it is not correct.  The `where` clause is evaluated before the the `order by` so there is no guarantee that the `@index` logic will pick up rows in a particular order.

Comment: By golly @GordonLinoff, that is true. Editing to use a nested subquery!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without variables, if you like.  The following requires duplicate removal, but on 13 records, this is minimal effort:

```
select *
from ((select d.*
       from distances d
       where city = '1'
       order by distance
       limit 3
      ) union 
      (select d.*
       from distances d
       where distance <= 20 and city = '1'
       order by distance
       limit 10
     )
    ) d
order by distance
limit 10;
```

Removing duplicates is inelegant, so the following does what you want with no duplicate removal:

```
      (select d.*
       from distances d
       where city = '1'
       order by distance
       limit 3
      ) union all
      (select d.*
       from distances d
       where distance <= 20 and city = '1'
       order by distance
       limit 3, 7
     )
```

The second subquery uses `offset`.  If the third distance is greater than 20, then the second part returns nothing.  Otherwise, if the third distance is less, then the first three records are ignored.